# Python and MySQL escape sequence for UNC path

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, unc

I am having a heck of a time getting a load data local infile to work with python.  I have tried a bunch of different ways in Python 3.6.5:

```
sqlpath = '\\corp.domain.com\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\SIM\'
sqlpath = "\\corp.domain.com\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\SIM\"
sqlpath = '\\\\corp.domain.com\\dept\\DCGSI\\Extracts\\SIM\\'
sqlpath = '//corp.domain.com/dept/DCGSI/Extracts/SIM/'
sqlpath = os.path.join("\\corp.domain.com","dept","DCGSI","Extracts","SIM")
sqlpath = os.path("\\\\corp.domain.com\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\SIM\")
```

I can't seem to get the escaping right for use in the following to save my sanity.  I have read at least 10 different posts here and tried all those suggestions.  What am I doing wrong so I can use the unc path in the loadQuery.

Here is the (CURRENT) entire script:

```
import config
import os
import pymysql


username = config.username
dbpassword = config.dbpassword
dbhost = config.dburl
conn =  pymysql.connect(host=dbhost, port=3306,user=username,password=dbpassword,db='dcgsreports',autocommit=True,local_infile=1)
path = '//corp.domain.com/dept/DCGSI/Extracts/SIM'
tables = []
files = []

fileNames = os.listdir(path)
for fileNames in fileNames:
    if fileNames.endswith(".csv"):
        files.append(fileNames)
        tables.append(fileNames.split('.')[0])

for f,t in zip(files, tables) :
    truncQuery = '''TRUNCATE TABLE %s''' %t
    loadQuery = '''LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '//corp.domain.com/dept/DCGSI/Extracts/SIM/%s' INTO TABLE %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;''' %(f, t)
    print(loadQuery)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(truncQuery)
    cursor.execute(loadQuery)
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

that print statement shows the following is what should be passed as the query (which should be correct):
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '//corp.domain.com/dept/DCGSI/Extracts/SIM/SIM_Availability.csv' INTO TABLE SIM_Availability FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '
' IGNORE 1 LINES;

All of the tables are empty though which seems to indicate that only the truncQuery is being executed.

Comment: Use a cursor and a prepared statement, then you don't have to worry about escaping.

Comment: I can't use a prepared statement to load multiple files from a directory, can I?  let me post the whole script.  I should have anyway

Comment: removed my previous answer.  I was not getting a syntax error with my answer, but the load query was not working.  I am not sure why this syntax is giving me problems.

Comment: Okay this for sure throws no syntax errors, BUT it appears that the \r\n portion is actually just creating a newline in the script and not passing \r\n as part of the query.

Comment: Use a raw string so the escape sequences will be sent literally.

Comment: Barmar, thanks.  I escaped the \r\n with \\r\\n and that seems to work, but I am still not seeing the data in the database.  I am now trying to figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider Python's os-agnostic `os.path.join()` and don't worry about back slashes or forward slashes. And use `string.format` or even Python 3.6's new [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (literal string interpolation like Perl's and Perl's *$string*). The modulus operator for string interpolation is not advised. Be sure to also `commit` actions:

```py
path = r"\\corp.domain.com\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\SIM"

for t, f in zip(tables, files) :

    truncQuery = "TRUNCATE TABLE `{t_name}`"
    loadQuery = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{f_name}'
                   INTO TABLE `{t_name}` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES 
                   TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;"""

    print(loadQuery)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(truncQuery.format(t_name = t)
    cursor.execute(loadQuery.format(f_name = os.path.join(path, f),
                                    t_name = t))

    cursor.close()
    conn.commit()
```

With f-string

```py
for t, f in zip(tables, files) :

    f_name = os.path.join(path, f)

    truncQuery = f"TRUNCATE TABLE `{t}`"
    loadQuery = f"""LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{f_name}'
                    INTO TABLE `{t}` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES 
                    TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;"""

    print(loadQuery)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(truncQuery)
    cursor.execute(loadQuery)

    cursor.close()
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: The first one gives a syntax error.  The second seems clean, but here is the ourput 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\\\corp.domain.com\\dept\\DCGSI\\Extracts\\SIM\\SIM_Availability.csv INTO TABLE SIM_Ava' at line 1"  for whatever reason it is inserting escape characters.  I am wondering if Spyder is doing something unexpected.

Comment: the edit results in the following error: 1017, "Can't find file 'b'\\\\corp.domain.comdeptDCGSIExtractsSIMSIM_Availability.csv''" (same error I have had before).  The first one errors on cursor.execute(loadQuery.format(f_name = os.path.join(path, f),
                                    t_name = t)

Comment: I am trying to make this agnostic in terms of where the script is run because mapping can be inconsistent, but UNC path is set.

Comment: the script is running on my machine with my username and I have full access to the path.  I also run other scripts that execute on that path and they work.  The only difference is the filename is hard coded in those scripts

Comment: indeed they are.  The difference is they look like the following: '''LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '//corp.domain.com/dept/DCGSI/Extracts/FE_CPI CapEx Projects Tasks.csv' INTO TABLE CPI_FE_Playbook_Tasks FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;'''
notice the file and table are hardcoded.  which I cannot do in this case.  and yes they do work.

Comment: also, yes I have tried copying that and the tables are still empty.  No Syntax error though.

Comment: I added that yes, they are still blank.  Posting the current code and the loadQuery Print.

Comment: Also, I shouldn't need the conn.commit since my connection string has autocommit = true I think

Comment: The only difference between the scripts is the for loops that are picking up multiple files and trying to insert them into different tables.  I am not getting any errors, but the tables in the database are empty.

Comment: Mother of God! so I very likely had the python code correct for hours.  The issue was with the loadQuery itself.  my files don't have an \r terminator for the lines.  just an \n.  Parfait I am marking your answer correct as you have been a great help.

Comment: I was almost going to ask to post a sample of your csv. Glad you found a solution. Be careful across OS systems as Windows programs like Excel tends to add carriages, `\r`, on line breaks for delimited files. And correct on `autocommit`.